# lshw tells me my processor is a 64 bits but my motherboard has a 32 bits width

Tags: linux, cpu, motherboard

Recently I noticed lshw tells me a strange thing.
Here is the first part of my lshw output:

```
bpetit-1025c
description: Notebook
product: 1025C (1025C)
vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
version: x.x
serial: C3OAAS000774
width: 32 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp-1.4 smp
configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook cpus=2 family=Eee PC...


 *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 1025C
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: x.xx
       serial: EeePC-0123456789
       slot: To be filled by O.E.M.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 1025C.0701
          date: 01/06/2012
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 1984KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd...
     *-cpu:0
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N2800   @ 1.86GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.6.1
          serial: 0003-0661-0000-0000-0000-0000
          slot: CPU 1
          size: 798MHz
          capacity: 1865MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 533MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 boot fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc ...
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=1 id=2 threads=2
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1-Cache
             size: 24KiB
             capacity: 24KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2-Cache
             size: 512KiB
             capacity: 512KiB
             capabilities: internal varies unified
        *-logicalcpu:0
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 2.1
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:1
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 2.2
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:2
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 2.3
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:3
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 2.4
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 13
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 2GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 0
             serial: [Empty]
             slot: DIMM0
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1066 MHz (0.9 ns)
             product: SSZ3128M8-EAEEF
             vendor: Xicor
             physical id: 1
             serial: 00000004
             slot: DIMM1
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
     *-cpu:1
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@1
          version: 6.6.1
          serial: 0003-0661-0000-0000-0000-0000
          size: 798MHz
          capacity: 798MHz
          capabilities: ht cpufreq
          configuration: id=2
        *-logicalcpu:0
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 2.1
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:1
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 2.2
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:2
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 2.3
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:3
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 2.4
             capabilities: logical
```

So here I see my processor is effectively a 64 bits one. However, I'm wondering how my motherboard can have a "32 bits width". I've browsed the web to find an answer, without success. I imagine it's just a technical fact that I don't know about.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there haven't really been 32/64 bit motherboards in years, but perhaps that is not true in notebooks. It would somewhat make sense since Atoms were 32-bit only for a long time, and computers with atom processors are rarely sold with more than 2 gb of ram, or even upgradeable to more than 4. Perhaps they were skimping on cost by only having 32-bit support.

For what it's worth, my desktop motherboard reports 64-bit width with a 64-bit processor and 64-bit OS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems my 32 bits motherboard is really restrictive: I tried to install xubuntu 12.10 64 bits and the installer tells me this: "This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. [...]". I don't understand why the constructor has put a 64 bits cpu with a 32 bits motherboard...