# Is my CPU 32-bit or 64-bit? Output from lshw, lscpu, getconf and /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: linux, 64-bit, 32-bit

I use Debian squeeze on a Toshiba Satellite. I want to know FOR SURE if my CPU is a 64 bit or a 32 bit. I ask this here because I am now very confused. What follow are the outputs of four different bash commands that allow the user to query exactly that (width of the CPU):

`grep getconf LONG_BIT` returns 32;

`grep /proc/cpuinfo` returns

```
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc amdc1e nonstop_tsc extd_apicid pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt nodeid_msr
```

and [this](http://hashprompt.blogspot.mx/2012/03/detecting-32-bit64-bit-processor-and.html) says that if `lm` appears highlighted then my CPU is 64-bit; well, it's not highlited.

`lshw` returns two different things: 32-bit motherboard and 64-bit processor (I saw [this post here](https://superuser.com/questions/490589/lshw-tells-me-my-processor-is-a-64-bits-but-my-motherboard-has-a-32-bits-width) and I thought that the answer applied to my case. Does it?)
And finally, `lscpu` returns:

```
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        64-bit
CPU(s):                1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            16
Model:                 6
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               800.000
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             64K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              512K
```

In conclusion: what's the conclusion here? Is my CPU a 32-bit or a 64-bit? I know I installed the 32-bit (i386) kernel, but that aside I need to know what my processor is.

Comment: One other sure-fire way to check would be trying to boot an x64 LiveCD.  It'll complain really quickly about a lack of 64-bit support.  Honestly though, if the machine was made in the past five years, it's going to be 64-bit, *especially* if it has virtualization features.

Comment: all AMD CPUs from opteron (2003) and later supports x86_64. No modern x86 CPUs are 32-bit only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generic commmand for all Linux distros :

```
grep -q '\<lm\>' /proc/cpuinfo && echo "My CPU is a 64 bits one" || echo "My CPU is a 32 bits one"
```

It's a *hardware* information : you can run a 32bit distro on a 64bit PC. The command will reveal the truth.

Comment: It returns 64. So is that the true width of my CPU?

Comment: Yes, that's it AdbekunkusMX

Comment: Thanks everyone and please excuse the obsesivity. Cheers!

Comment: Note that this **only works for x86** and not other platforms. Many people have been mistaken and run this on ARM which obviously doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page on the Gentoo wiki](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Safe_Cflags/AMD#Athlon_X2_7x50.2C_Phenom_X3.2FX4.2C_Phenom_II.2C_Athlon_II_X2.2FX3.2FX4.2C_Turion_II), your CPU (Family 16, Model 6, Stepping 3) is 64-bit.